# How come I'm getting an error of "could not determine executable to run"?

Tags: javascript, terminal, typeorm, npx

As I stated in the title, I'm getting an error of "could not determine executable to run" When I run,

```
npx typeform init --name tasksmanager --database postgres
```

[Picture of the terminal with the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMBiS.png)

I'm trying to setup the typeform boilterplate [typeform quick-start link](https://typeorm.io/#quick-start) and for some reason this is happening, I even tried running,

```
npx create-react-app react-task-manager --template
```

and I had no problem setting up my react app.

Comment: Well it its `typeorm`.